# How to make a C++ class whose objects can only be dynamically allocated?

Tags: c++

The problem is to create a class such that the non-dynamic allocation of object causes compiler error.

For example :

```
Employee e1;  // compiler error
Employee *e3 = new Employee; // works fine
```

Comment: Cannot be done. The only thing you can do is Make the constructor private, and have a `static` factory that constructs a `new` instance of the class.

Comment: Creating such a class *is* certainly a problem. The solution is, just don't do it. Seriously, this sounds like an XY problem to me, and to get a meaningful answer you should tell us what you're trying to accomplish by doing this, and perhaps then we can help you work out a better way of accomplishing your end goal.

Comment: That's a very odd requirement. Why would you impose such restrictions? Trying to prevent programmers from doing things they'd normally do without explanation is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a private destructor in the class. When you make a private destructor, the compiler would generate a compiler error for non-dynamically allocated objects because compiler need to remove them from stack segment once they are not in use.

Comment: And how do you propose to `delete` those objects?

Comment: we create a friend function destruct() which can be called by users of class to destroy objects.

Comment: That seems backwards. Couldn't I circumvent that by using placement new?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <memory>

struct S {
    static std::unique_ptr<S> create() {
        return std::unique_ptr<S>(new S);
    }

private:
    S() {}
};

int main() {
    auto ptr = S::create();
}
```

Note that using the following doesn't work as expected:

```
S() = default;
```

I guess it is due to the fact that the class is treated as an aggregate and thus the following still works for it:

```
S s{};
```

Moreover, the following `create` function does not work in the example above:

```
static std::unique_ptr<S> create() {
    return std::make_unique<S>();
}
```

That's because `make_unique` must be able to access the constructor to do its work, but this is not possible for the constructor is private.

Comment: Did you mean `S()=delete`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, I meant `S() = default;`. Try to use it in the example and add this line to the `main` function: `S s{};`. You'll see the _unexpected_ (?) result then. I would do that for you, but godbolt is not usable from mobile. :-(

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your constructors private and make a factory returning a shared pointer on the object.